# $P(x)$ has integer coefficients and admits $4$ integer roots. Prove that $P(x) = 2$ does not admit integer roots.

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

I was reading a book (*21 Aulas de Matemática Olímpica, C. Shine*) and I came across the following question:

> $P(x)$ has integer coefficients and admits $4$ integer roots. Prove that $P(x) = 2$ does not admit integer roots.

I have no idea how to solve it, but because of the topic that was being addressed, I suppose the solution needs the polynomial remainder theorem. Can anyone give any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If one allows multiple roots, the statement is not quite true: consider
$$P(x) = (x+1)^3 (x+2)$$
or
$$P(x) = (x+1)^2 (x-1)(x-2)$$
for example.

If the four integer roots are distinct, then
$$P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)g(x)$$
for distinct integers $a, b, c, d$. Then $P(t) = 2$ for an integer $t$ would mean that an integer divisor of $2$ (positive or negative) can be written as a product of four different integers - that is not possible.